# JSON serialize and deserialize C# with Partial objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

This is the final JSON object I am look for -

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",      
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"         <-- Added by my application
  }
}
```

In this example, I don't own firstName, lastName and somepart of address. My part of logic just needs to inject age and address. Is there a way to not duplicate the entire object on my side? Can I just have an object like this -

```
public class AdditionalAddressInfo
{
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalUserInfo
{
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to serialize this and add to the incoming JSON.

Comment: Have you considered to use a [json patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) for that? [There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch.jsonpatchdocument?view=aspnetcore-3.0) is a .NET implementation of it and [how to article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for .NET Core. And 3rd party [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Marvin.JsonPatch) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DynamicObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject) for partial deserialize, so that you don't need to know about other properties:

```
var jsonString = @"{
                      ""firstName"": ""John"",
                      ""lastName"": ""Smith"",
                      ""address"": {
                        ""streetAddress"": ""21 2nd Street"",      
                        ""city"": ""New York"",
                        ""state"": ""NY"",     
                      }
                    }";

dynamic dynoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);

//adding age
AdditionalUserInfo additionalUserInfo = new AdditionalUserInfo();
additionalUserInfo.age = 27;
dynoObject.age = additionalUserInfo.age;

//adding postalCode
AdditionalAddressInfo additionalAddressInfo = new AdditionalAddressInfo();
additionalAddressInfo.postalCode = "10021 - 3100";
dynoObject.address.postalCode = additionalAddressInfo.postalCode;

var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynoObject);
```

Then new Json would be as expected:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",      
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly add the new values to Json by modifying the JObject. For example,

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var address = jObj["address"] as JObject;
address.Add("postalCode","10021-3100");
jObj.Add("age",27);
var result = jObj.ToString();
```

Output

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "age": 27
}
```